# UICollectionViewController Moving cells around in the storyboard

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

just wondering if its possible to move cells around the storyboard and how to do so? Preferably using storyboards, and if not then using swift, and if not using swift I can try to do it in objective-c. I need to move my ui navbar image on top of the cell.
[image]

Comment: can you please share the original screenshot that actually what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Yes and plz explain bit more about your idea